# Dropdown Menu Selection to Populate Form

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Hi all,

I am trying to populate a form from MySQL using a dropdown menu to select the row I want displayed.
The dropdown is displaying the items I need. But what I want to do is select one of the items in the dropdown, which will fill in the form with the items I need for editing.

Here is the code I have so far, including the form. Any help you guys can give would be really appreciated.

The Select:

```
                                 <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading"> Manage Tours</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                                <form role="form" method="post" action="">
              <label for="singleSelect">Choose Tour to Edit</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="tour_select">
     <?php 
     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT tour_name FROM tours order by id");

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
         echo "<option value='" . $row['tour_name'] . "'>" . $row['tour_name'] . "</option>";
     ?>
 </select>
```

This works fine.

The form, which also works fine with a simple select query:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Tour Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="tour_name" value="<?php echo $row['tour_name']; ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Destination</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="tour_to" rows="4"><?php echo $row['tour_to']; ?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Collection</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="tour_from" rows="4"><?php echo $row['tour_from']; ?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Date</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="tour_date" value="<?php echo $row['tour_date']; ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Pickup Time</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="tour_time" value="<?php echo $row['tour_time']; ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Itinerary</label>
                                        <textarea class="tinymce" id="tinymce" name="tour_details" rows="12" ><?php echo $row['tour_details']; ?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                                </form>
```

But, when I select an option from the dropdown, I need the form to be populated with the data from that database table row. I hope I am making sense.
I have searched for days on Google but found nothing.

I have changed the form from a dropdown to an html table with a Delete button.

Here is the code with table:

```
    <?php
                      if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
   $remove = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `tours` WHERE `id` = $id");

   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $remove->bind_param('ssssss', $id);

   if(!$remove->execute() === true) {
       echo $mysqli->error;               
   }
}
                      }
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM tours";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


?>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_name']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_to']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_from']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_date']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_time']; ?></td>
                          <td><input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" onclick="" /></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      <?php
}
?>
                    </table>
                                    </form>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to use the `<select>`'s name attribute in a POST that will take the value chosen and used in the next page's query in a SELECT; best I can make of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to preselect a particular tour with `$tour_id = 5`. You can then modify your code to:

`echo "<option value='" . $row['tour_name'] . "'" . ($row['id'] == $tour_id ? " selected" : "") . ">" . $row['tour_name'] . "</option>";`

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried but nothing works. I have since changed to display the data in a table with a button to delete with name="Delete". I am using        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
   $remove = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `tours` WHERE `id` = ?");

   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $remove->bind_param('s', $id);

   if(!$remove->execute() === true) {
       echo $mysqli->error;               
   }
}
       }

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution should anyone need it in future.

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['Delete'])){
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $count = count($checkbox);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

        if(!empty($checkbox[$i])){ /* CHECK IF CHECKBOX IS CLICKED OR NOT */

        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$checkbox[$i]); /* ESCAPE STRINGS */
        mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM tours WHERE id = '$id'"); /* EXECUTE QUERY AND USE ' ' (apostrophe) IN YOUR VARIABLE */

        } /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY CHECKBOX */

    } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

} /* END OF ISSET DELETE */

                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM tours";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row['id']);
?>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_name']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_to']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_from']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_date']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['tour_time']; ?></td>
                          <?php echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='$id'></td>"; ?>
                         </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      <?php
}
?>
```

Thanks all for the help. Really appreciate it.